# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n) * x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms

As in the title, I'm in 
quest for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n)\cdot x^n$, where $0 \le x \lt 1$

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5En+*+log+n) says: $-\operatorname{PolyLog}^{(1, 0)}(0, x)$, but I don't understand what that means. (Of course, PolyLog stays for the polylogarithm).

*Background*

It's about "how many bits I need to encode a real number $0 < r < 1$ with a tolerance $\delta/2$? The "naive" response is $-log_2(\delta)$.

Nevertheless (long story short) I need a different approach:

1. I can encode every positive integer $n$ with approximately $C\cdot\log(n)$ bits
2. Let $0 < x_i < 1$ be a pseudo-random sequence, and let $N$ be the 1st index so that $r-\delta/2 <x_N< r+\delta/2$.
   Then let's say that we can transmit  $r$ via $N$ (with the tolerance $\delta$). So we need $C\cdot\log(N)$ bits...
3. But then I need the *expected* value
   $E(C\cdot\log(N)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C\cdot\log(n)\cdot\delta\cdot(1-\delta)^{n-1}$ 
   $=C\cdot{\delta\over1-\delta} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(n) \cdot (1-\delta)^n$

Comment: When you say "log" do you mean log base-10 or natural logarithm?

Comment: I suspect it has no closed form better than that. What do you need this for?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a link to the Wolfram alpha output.

Comment: @R.Burton natural logarithm

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry, too long to explain now... maybe I'll edit the question.

Comment: The closed form with PolyLog should be ok for me ... if only I could understand what the "exponent" $^{(1,0)}$ means.

Answer (score 1):

Definition of Polylogarithm:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

No closed form exists in terms of *elementary* functions (addition, multiplication, powers, etc.), at least not in terms of real functions. You *might* be able to write it as a complex-valued function or improper integral.

Given that the polylogarithm is already a special function, I suspect that any closed form will be in terms of special functions rather than something nice.

Comment: Yes, I read that, so I'd understand what $PolyLog(0,q)$ means. What I _don't_ understand is the "exponent" $^{(1,0)}$

Comment: After working on it for a bit, I don't think that your sum has anything to do with polylogarithms at all. I have no idea what "$-PolyLog^{(1,0)}(0,x)$" is supposed to mean; it might be an error. Either way,  The closest I can get to approximating the curve without spending more time on it is approximately $\frac{x^2}{1.2-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for spending time on that! Where that approximation come from?

Comment: Wild guess based on the form of the graph (which is similar visually similar to to $\frac{x^2}{(a-x)^2}$, then adjusting $a$ until I got as close to $\sum_{n=1}^{1000 }\log(n)x^n$ as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900284/lerch-transcendent-textlerchphi0-1-0-left-frac12-0-2-right?s=13|29.6380) what the notation $f^{(1,0)}$ means in Wolfram Alpha: it's the derivative wrt the 1st variable.

So the response is $-\frac{\partial \operatorname{Li}(s,t)}{\partial s}\bigg|_{(s=0, t=x)}$